# Is there any way to synchronize parent and child in C using one pipe in Unix?

Tags: c, unix, pipe, synchronize

Suppose both parent and child use one pipe for writing and reading means when one writes then only other read otherwise it blocks. Is there any way to do it? I tried to do it with sleep function but due to race conditions, it does not give the correct output. 
This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MSGSIZE 16
main ()
{
  int i;
  char *msg = "How are you?";
  char inbuff[MSGSIZE];
  int p[2];
  pid_t ret;
  pipe (p);
  ret = fork ();
  if (ret > 0)
    {
      i = 0;
      while (i < 10)
        {
          write (p[1], msg, MSGSIZE);
          sleep (2);
          read (p[0], inbuff, MSGSIZE);
          printf ("Parent: %s\n", inbuff);
          i++;
        }
    exit(1);
    }
  else
    {
      i = 0;
      while (i < 10)
        {
          sleep (1);
          read (p[0], inbuff, MSGSIZE);
          printf ("Child: %s\n", inbuff);
          write (p[1], "i am fine", strlen ("i am fine"));
          i++;
        }
    }
  exit (0);
}
```

Comment: A pipe has two ends, normally ;) - perhaps you should post some code so we can see exactly what you've tried.

Comment: I have added the code but all new lines are eaten. How should I post the code correctly

Comment: @aditya, ident with 4 spaces. There is a button over the edit area (hover over it to get a description,) that does that automatically for any selected text.

Comment: @adiya, the button is the one with the 0s and 1s and is called "Code Sample".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pipe() creates two filedescriptor, one for reading and an another for writing. For two way communication, you need to create two pipes (four filedescriptors).

Answer (score 6):

You can't do bi-directional synchronization on a single pipe.

You can do bi-directional synchronization on a Unix-domain socket.

Comment: Note that you can easily create a unix-domain socket that acts like a bidirectional pipe using the `socketpair()` call